# Read hexadecimal from file with scilab

Tags: scilab

I have a file that looks like the following:

```
Time    M1:Address 480008C0
0   79F9446F
0.000125    7AE7446B
0.00025 7BA8446F
...
```

It is 2 numbers separated by a tab, one is a hexadecimal number. I am looking to read these into a decimal array in scilab. I have tried to open and read the file as follows:

```
u=mopen('proper_log_with_fail.txt','r'); // open the file for reading
s = mscanf(u, '%s'); // Forget the first line
[time,val]=mfscanf(u,'%e\t%x'); // Get the second line
```

So i am not ever able to read any values ...? I cannot even read the first string? Am i doing something super obvious wrong?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: @user1149326 I have not yet had a chance to try it. But thank-you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a typo, but for the first row you are using `mscanf` which should be [`mfscanf`](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.0/en_US/mfscanf.html) for reading from file. When changing this it shows that your first line isn't matching, note that `%s`only matches one word and then stops at the next whitespace. 
To read (and discard) the first line, use [`mgetl`](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.0/en_US/mgetl.html) and tell it to read 1 line. If the rest of the input file is data formatted the same way, you can use the `niter` argument of [`mfscanf`](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.0/en_US/mfscanf.html) to keep matching up until the end of the file (EOF).

```
file_path = 'proper_log_with_fail.txt'; 

// open the file for reading
fd=mopen(file_path,'r'); 

// Read/display header line
number_of_lines_to_read = 1;
header = mgetl(fd, number_of_lines_to_read);
disp(header);

// Scan all lines up until EOF 
niter = -1
s = mfscanf(niter, fd, '%e %x'); 
disp(s)

// Close the file after reading
mclose(fd)
```